# CLI/C++ Converting "this" pointer to an integer

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to trace managed object creation/disposing in a CLI/C++ prog:

```
::System::Diagnostics::Trace::WriteLine(String::Format(
    "Created {0} #{1:X8}", 
    this->GetType()->Name,
    ((UInt64)this).ToString()));
```

Which fails with

`error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'MyType ^const ' to 'unsigned __int64'`

Is there a way to keep track of the unique object IDs this way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, why this doesn't work. Managed handle types `^` aren't pointers. They aren't just addresses. An instance of a managed type can and will be [moved around in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark-compact_algorithm) by GC, so addresses aren't stable; hence why it wouldn't let you do such a cast (as GC can execute at any moment, and you do not know when, any attempt to use such an address as a raw value is inherently a race condition).

Another thing that is often recommended, but doesn't actually work, is `Object.GetHashCode()`. For one thing, it returns an `int`, obviously not enough to be unique on x64. Furthermore, the documentation doesn't guarantee that values are unique, and they actually aren't in 2.0+.

The only working solution is to create a an instance of  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle` for your object, and then cast it to `IntPtr` - that is guaranteed to be both unique, and stable.

Comment: This has the caveat that you have to remember to cleanup the GCHandle when you are done, no?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `GCHandle` type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx. Looks like it would do what you want, though it looks it would be a bit of a pain to use for your purposes...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could cast `this` to some integral value for display, it probably wouldn't be a useful unique identifier. This is because unlike C++, in C++/CLI the location of a (managed) object (and by extension the value of this) can potentially change *during* that object's lifetime. The (logically) same object could print two different strings at different points in the program.

Answer (score -1):

MyType ^const is a reference type. Hence it's in the managed memory space, and you can't get direct memory pointers to these types, as they can change at any time.

> Is there a way to keep track of the unique object IDs this way? Thanks!

You could use MyType.GetHashCode();